# Optimization Technique For Update Query in MySQL 5.1.73-log

Tags: mysql, update, mysql-5.1, explain

I am trying to optimize an update query on InnoDB table in MySQL 5.1.73-log.
As per my understanding we can not use EXPLAIN on update query for 5.1 version.
So what will be the alternate course of action for such cases. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To optimize the UPDATE query, you must to optimize the corresponding SELECT query.

Comment: If you would like to show us the `UPDATE` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, there may be some obvious tips.  (Meanwhile, please plan upgrading in the near future.)